# How can I set HTTP headers using Amazon S3 bucket policies?

Tags: amazon-s3, http-headers

So [apparently](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=941136) Firefox [won't load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control) @font-face fonts from another domain unless those fonts are returned with a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` header.

How can I set this header on a key prefix using Amazon S3 bucket policies? Or will I have to manually add it to each object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is finally possible: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Comment: Actually, I don't think it is possible to actually have resources return with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`. You can set any origin to be allowed, but S3 seems to always reply with whatever is set as the `Origin` header, instead of `*`.